# How do i get strongly consistency in GAE in Python enviroment

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I got a website, most like a blog, and when I submit a post it immediately put it in the db and update the cache too. It looks like that when the cache try to update itself, the db is not updated, and I got a cache out of date, with I got a front page without the last post, I tried putting `time.sleep(1)`, and then it worked but I want to know if that have to be with that I'm not using a parent for my entities, and if that is how may I do that?

```
def cachFront(update=False):
    key="top"
    entradas=memcache.get(key)
    if entradas is None or update:
        logging.error("DB QUERY")
        post= db.GqlQuery("select * from dbEntradas order by fecha_creacion desc limit 10")
        entradas=list(post)
        memcache.set(key, entradas)
    return entradas


class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        entradas= cachFront()
        self.render("index.html", entradas=entradas)


class NewPostHandler(Handler):

    def renderizar(self, error="", titulo="", post=""):
        self.render("entradas.html", titulo=titulo, post=post, error=error)

    def get(self):
        self.render("entradas.html")

    def post(self):
        titulo= self.request.get("title")
        topic= self.request.get("topic")
        post= self.request.get("post")

        if titulo and post  and (topic!="Choose one.."):
            entrada= post_db.dbEntradas(title=titulo, post=post, topic=topic)
            entrada.put()
            time.sleep(1)// if i commet this line when i redirect i do not get a cache update intead i got the old page
            cachFront(True)
            self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: It would probably be easier for you to update your `cachFront` function to accept the newly saved `entrada` and manually prepend it to the result of your `GqlQuery` if it isn't returned there.

Comment: what im doing is writing to the database, and then updating the cache from then, i can not update the cache first in that way, because what im caching here is a list of rows of the 10 recently posts

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I am suggesting you do the save and then cache inside of your post method. Not cache and then save. I will post an answer illustrating it.

Comment: I know this is outside of the scope of your question but also consider moving from `db` to `ndb`. The api is nice and you get memcache'd entities for free for a lot of operations.

Comment: thx men, i saw ur comment and it help  me, with ndb im going to try, im new in all of this and im making a course the tech me the basic with db so, im gonna look and learn ndb later, but thx anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the change I made to `cachFront` and to the call to `cachFront` inside of your `post` method to manually prepend your entry in the case where eventual consistency hasn't replicated.

```
def cachFront(update=False, prepend=None):
    key="top"
    entradas=memcache.get(key)
    if entradas is None or update:
        logging.error("DB QUERY")
        post= db.GqlQuery("select * from dbEntradas order by fecha_creacion desc limit 10")
        entradas=list(post)
        # manually prepend item to cache if it isn't available yet because
        # of eventual consistency
        if prepend and (not entradas or not entradas[0].key == prepend.key):
            entradas.insert(0, prepend)
            entradas = entradas[0:10]
        memcache.set(key, entradas)
    return entradas


class MainHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        entradas= cachFront()
        self.render("index.html", entradas=entradas)


class NewPostHandler(Handler):

    def renderizar(self, error="", titulo="", post=""):
        self.render("entradas.html", titulo=titulo, post=post, error=error)

    def get(self):
        self.render("entradas.html")

    def post(self):
        titulo= self.request.get("title")
        topic= self.request.get("topic")
        post= self.request.get("post")

        if titulo and post  and (topic!="Choose one.."):
            entrada= post_db.dbEntradas(title=titulo, post=post, topic=topic)
            entrada.put()
            cachFront(update=True, prepend=entrada)
            self.redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question specifically, yes, you could use parent / ancestor entities to solve your problem.  If you expect to never make a write to your dbEntradas entities more than around 1/second, then this can be a fine solution.

Using parent entities tells datastore to keep all of those entities that share an ancestor relationship on the same server (basically to not replicate the data).  Thus, you won't have to use time.sleep() to allow your entity to be written, as the following GQL call will be guaranteed to see the data from your earlier put.

You will need to choose one entity that will be the parent of all entities, and use that every time you make a new entrada:

```
post_db.dbEntradas(title=titulo, post=post, topic=topic, parent=post_parent)
```

In this case, I would suggest just making your first post the default parent, and grab its key.  So your code would become:

```
def post(self):
    titulo= self.request.get("title")
    topic= self.request.get("topic")
    post= self.request.get("post")

    if titulo and post  and (topic!="Choose one.."):
        parent_entrada = post_db.dbEntradas.query(post_db.dbEntradas.id == [[first_post_id_here]]).get()

        entrada= post_db.dbEntradas(title=titulo, post=post, topic=topic, parent = parent_entrada)
        entrada.put()
        cachFront(True)
        self.redirect('/')
```

Comment: This may work but it will break a lot of get by id type fetches unless you always specify the parent entity.

Comment: I was thinking in that way, and reading and GAE documentation  i found this porcedure Key.from_path(*path, parent=None, namespace=None), that generates a key automaticly to apply as ancestor